# highlight main menu item when sub item is open

Tags: jquery, html, css

In my web site I have a menu bar with drop down menus for some of the items. When viewing one of the sub-pages I want the parent item in the menu bar to be highlighted (`class='active`).

Here is my code:

```
<div id="sidebar-left">
    <div class="menu">
        <ul class="listeohne">
            <li class="color1" id='active'><a href="index.php">Startseite</a>
            </li>
            <li class="color2"><a href="">Wer wir sind</a>

                <ul>
                    <li class="whiteback">
<a href="werwirsind.php">Einf&uuml;hrung</a> 
                    </li>
                    <li class="whiteback"><a href="statuten.php">Statuten</a> 
                    </li>
                    <li class="whiteback"><a href="vorstand.php">Vorstand </a> 
                    </li>
                    <li class="whiteback borderbottomgrey"><a href="pdf/organigramm_svnw_13.pdf">Organisation </a> 
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
```

View example site www.nzz.ch. My site is www.svnw.ch.

I have tried numerous solutions described in this forum, but none of them works for me, but then I am not an expert.

Comment: Could you post any code you already tried?

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: `<div id="sidebar-left">
        <div class="menu">
          <ul class="listeohne">
 <li class="color1" id='active'>
  <a href="index.php">Startseite</a>
 </li>
 
<li class="color2"> <a href="" >
  Wer wir sind</a>
   <ul>
   <li class="whiteback" ><a href="werwirsind.php">Einf&uuml;hrung</a> </li>
   <li class="whiteback" ><a href="statuten.php" >Statuten</a>  </li>
   <li class="whiteback" ><a href="vorstand.php" >Vorstand </a> </li> 
   <li class="whiteback borderbottomgrey" ><a href="pdf/organigramm_svnw_13.pdf" >Organisation </a> </li>   
   </ul>
 </li>
`

Answer (score 0):

Get the link of the page you are currently one :

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
```

or

```
$(location).attr('href');
```

via [Get current URL in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406192/how-to-get-the-current-url-in-jquery)

then search in the menu for the a having the href equal with "pathname" and add the ".active" class!

```
 $('a[href$="ABC"]').






 $(function(){
    var actlink = $(location).attr('href');

    $('a[href$="actlink"]').parent("li").addClass('active');
})
```

or

```
$(function(){
    var actlink = $(location).attr('href');

    $('ul > li > a[href$="actlink"]').parent("li").addClass('active');
});
```

Don't know for sure it works. Haven't tested it!

Comment: Thank you. Do I have to do this for each list item (just beginning to learn java(jquery)?

Comment: So am i!

And this should to the trick 

     $(function(){
 var actlink = $(location).attr('href');

 $('a[href$="actlink"]').parent("li").addClass('active');
});

if not, try replacing a[href$="actlink"] with li > ul a[href$="actlink"]

and don't forget to accept my answer:D

Comment: Haven't been able to make it work. Could it be because my documents are .php? I placed the script in the head section of the index page like this: <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js">  
   $(function(){ var actlink = $(location).attr('href'); $(li > ul'a[href$="actlink"]').parent("li").addClass('active'); })
</script>

Comment: I couldn't make it work, either! Even though, i don't think the idea is bad. I think the searching for the a with matching href isn't correct!