# Highlighting a header menu item when on any of its sub pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menu, highlight

I have a main `nav` in the header of my site with 8 or so links.

Within most of these pages, there is a sub navigation down the left hand side.

I would like to be able to highlight the current link in the header, when you are on any of it's sub pages.

I can't do this manually because the header links are edited globally through a cms, so it will require some sort of JavaScript to be applied to each of the sub pages telling the main header link to be highlighted.

The script to highlight the current sub-page item would be nice to know as well, but not essential.  I know it's out there somewhere, but I've always seemed to have a hell of a time figuring out how to make it work.

http://ccc.my-dms.net/The-Stone-Collection-New-Arrivals.htm

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Rather than making us dig through your site, could reproduce a minimal/ [short, self-contained correct/compilable example](http://sscce.org/) for us to work with? Post the relevant code *here* (JavaScript/jQuery, HTML and CSS) and, ideally, post a live demo at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar; please: *help us* to help **you**.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally use PHP and define a variable like 
`$page = "home";`
Then I would check for it in the header with an if statement. If you can't do it in PHP it can be done by getting the current url with jQuery.

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
```

Then you could check with an if statement and change the class of the button if it is true.

Or if you want just the html file name (test.html) you can do this.

```
var pathname = document.location.pathname.match(/[^\/]+$/)[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Add, a drop-down on every menu item that have sub-pages firstly (i guess you don't have to show it..keep it hidden)

then, use something like this

```
 $(function(){
    var actlink = $(location).attr('href');

    $('ul > li > a[href$="actlink"]').parent("li").addClass('active');
});
```

I also suggested it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18449000/highlight-main-menu-item-when-sub-item-is-open/18449325?noredirect=1#comment27111658_18449325)